# Show that the following operator is not a surjection.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, functions, operator-theory

> *"Take $X=C([0,1])$ with the uniform norm, $\|f\|=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$, and define the operator $T:X\to X$ by,
>   $$T(f)(x)=f(x)-\int_0^1f(s)ds$$
>   Show that $T$ is not a surjection"*.

Here is what I have done:

Saying that $T$ is **not** a surjection means that $\exists\, g\in X:\nexists f\in X:Tf=g$

So we consider,

$$T(f)(x)=f(x)-\int_0^1f(s)ds=g(x)$$

$$\implies\int_0^1f(x)dx-\int_0^1\int_0^1f(s)ds\,dx=\int_0^1g(x)dx$$

$$\implies0=\int_0^1g(x)dx$$

In the solutions I have, it says that two functions are equal if we obtain the same value after evaluating their integrals over the interval. Is this enough to show that $T$ is not a surjection? I am not entirely convinced.

Clearly the only $g\in X$ for which this holds is $g=0$, the zero function in $X$. But since $g\in X$ was arbitrary, and not every $g\in C([0,1])$ satisfies $\int_0^1g(x)dx=0$, $T$ is not a surjection?

Is my thinking here correct?

Comment: What you've shown is that if $g$ is in the image of $T$, then $g$ must have integral $0$. Since not every $g\in X$ has integral $0$, this means that not every $g$ can be in the image of $T$, and hence $T$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the solutions I have, it says that two functions are equal if we obtain the same value after evaluating their integrals over the interval. Is this enough to show that $T$ is not a surjection? I am not entirely convinced.

That statement is backwards: If two functions are equal, then obviously they have the same integral, but there are plenty of non-zero functions in $C([0,1])$ whose integral is $0$. For example, $f(x) = \sin(2\pi x)$. Having the same integral is nowhere near enough information to say that two functions are equal.

> Clearly the only $g\in X$ for which this holds is $g=0$, the zero function in $X$.

Clearly not.

> But since $g\in X$ was arbitrary, and not every $g\in C([0,1])$ satisfies $\int_0^1g(x)dx=0$, $T$ is not a surjection?

$g$ is not arbitrary. To show that $T$ is not a surjection, you just have to find *a single function* that is not in its image. You don't have to prove it for a class of functions, but just show that there is at least one function for which this condition fails.

As Joey Zou has pointed out, you have shown that for $g = Tf$, it must be true that $\int_0^1 g(x)dx = 0$. So what you need to do now is give a specific example of a function in $C([0,1])$ whose integral is not $0$. Then that function cannot be the image of any $f$, so $T$ cannot be surjective.